# c++ argv[1] something strange

Tags: c++, argv

I got strange problem parsing C++ arguments from `argv[]`. Here is some sample of code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i=0; i <argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s|\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
};
```

When I run this program like this:

```
./myprogram --aaa-a --bbb-b --ccc-c
```

the result I get is like:

```
argv[0] = myprogram|
argv[1] = --aaa-a --bbb-b|
argv[2] = --ccc-c
```

but when I try:

```
./myprogram --aaa-a  --bbb-b --ccc-c
```

with additional space between aa and bb, I got:

```
argv[0] = myprogram|
argv[1] = --aaa-a|
argv[2] =  --bbb-b|
argv[3] = --ccc-c|
```

Does anyone can give me a clue what is happening here?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @zenith: yes, You are right.
@ Matt McNabb: standard Debian dash.
also I removed -O2 flag and now it works as expected.

Comment: Not [reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/852e8bf3919cfd2f). You'll have to provide more precise information (environment, compiler, compilation args, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you have a [non-breakable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (or any character that's displayed as space) between `--aaa-a` and `--bbb-b`. Remove the whole command line and write it again from scratch.

Comment: Also, if this is the problem, then to the OP: please actually copy and paste. Don't just re-type your code, input and output in your question. If you *had* copied and pasted, the non-breaking space would have been part of the question, we would be able to verify that this is the problem.